# Как задать внутреннюю тень inset снизу

Tags: css, css3, css-animation

По умолчанию она может быть только верху и с лево

```css
body>div {
  margin: 60px 60px;
    width: 500px;
    height: 309px;
    background: #6d6d6d;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 3.3em;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 297px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.border:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0px 23px #53ea93;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="border">Hover the mouse</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задавая отрицательные значения, вы можете смещать ее вниз и вправо (вместо левой и верхней сторон по умолчанию):

```
.border:hover {
    box-shadow: inset 0 -23px #53ea93;
}
```

**P.S.** https://www.cssmatic.com/box-shadow играйтесь на здоровье (не реклама, первая же ссылка в гугле)